# JQuery WYSIWYG Editor with file upload capabilities

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Are there any JQuery WYSIWYG editor plug-ins with file upload capabilities?  Or would I need to mesh the two separate plug-ins together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php), [CkEditor](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery), [Xinha](http://www.jquerylabs.com/xinha-jquery-plugin.html) (Xena)

Unless you want to use file manager as standalone jquery plugin?

I personaly use CkEditor (previous FckEditor) since in version 3.0 it has been completely rewritten from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I use [CkUploader](http://ckuploader.com), nice for image upload

Comment: please put a link to CkUploader: `[linktext](url)`